# How does the Google Play Store decide which country the user is in?

Tags: android, google-play, google-account

I have an app which is only available for users in my country. The country doesn't matter for this. I'm regularly contacted by users who're foreigners, with foreign phones but living in my country and they cannot download the app.

How can they bypass this problem? Would having a local sim from my country solve it? Or is it some kind of settings for your google account?

Comment: It has nothing to do with your google account, probably has to do with a combination of the sim and/or device

Comment: I think you need to step back and consider who you want to restrict it to and why.  Do you want to restrict it to citizens?  People living in the country?  People physically in the country (can tourists use your app)?  The general reason to use country restrictions is legal-  some law in the country makes your app illegal and you want to block it.   Or some law in your host country makes it illegal to export to other countries.  Using it to limit users to a certain country isn't generally done.

Comment: The app is not mine, I'm managing/building it. There are some legal reasons yes, mostly because its a finance app. However any EU citizen can use it, but they only market it on the local market and its connected to specific local services.

Comment: But it sounds like you want at least part of the other market (people who can't download it now but want to) to be able to get it.  Your best option may be just to open it up to the EU as a whole, or to neighboring/high imigrant rate countries.  Since you aren't marketing it outside a certain area, its unlikely someone who lives on the other side of the continent and can't use it is likely to run into it, so being less restricted will likely fix the problem without too much of the other type of problem (people who can't use it download it).

Comment: Play Store country is changed when setting a payment method. Check https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7431675?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7431675?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

It's a Google Account setting.